Fetch all IDs from API
I am currently working on fetching data from an API endpoint structured as follows: http://api.com/api/placements/{placementsid}. This endpoint allows me to retrieve data for a specific placement by using a unique placementsid.
The challenge I am facing is:
When I specify a single placementsid in the URL, the API returns data for only that specific placement.However, my objective is to retrieve data for all placements available in the system.
Questions:
How can I modify my approach to fetch all placement IDs from this API endpoint?
Is there a specific method or endpoint that allows me to get a list of all placementsid values?
Once I have all the placement IDs, how do I structure my pipeline to iterate over each ID and fetch the corresponding data?
What should I specify in the "Relative URL" field of my data source configuration to ensure I can dynamically fetch data for each placement ID?
What are the best practices for aggregating or storing the fetched data in Azure Data Factory (ADF)?
Should I use a particular activity or sequence of activities in ADF to handle this process efficiently?
enter image description here
enter image description here

Is this a custom API or one already present in Azure? And cannot you just use something like a for loop?

its custom Api and i m new in data factory for i dont know how to loop

Programming language?

If your API has next URL in the current result JSON body or header then you can try Pagination in ADF pipeline to copy all of your pages data.
If you don't have the API like that, then you should have the list of your PlacementID's and use a loop to iterate through that list to get your requirement done.
In the pipeline, take a For-Each activity and give the array of Placement IDs to the For-each expression.
Inside For-each activity, take a copy activity and create source and sink datasets for those like below. In source REST dataset, create a string parameter and use that in the Relative URL.

Build your Relative URL using concat() function. For sample I have created the Relative URL like @concat('?page=',dataset().Id) which will give the URL like ?page=1 when the value of Id is 1. So, build your URL same like this.

Do the same in the sink dataset as well. For sample, I took JSON dataset as sink.

Use this to generate dynamic file names in each iteration.

Give these datasets as copy activity source and sink. In source, give current value @item() to the source dataset parameter.

In the sink, build the file name like @concat('myfile',item(),'.json').

Now, debug your pipeline and you will get your output files.


Thanks for your replay but in my API i dont have next page option

Then you need to use the loop option as mentioned in the above answer. But you should have all the required placement ids as list for that. Without that you can't loop through.

What i need to add on for each setting  (items )

can you tell me how can i use loop please

You need to add the placement ids array to the For-each expression. Check this doc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-for-each-activity

So i need add all plaement id manulaay tere is no way to get id auto

Yes, you need all the placement ids list to achieve your requirement.
